# more active screens / views in shell caliburn micro or another MVVM framework

Tags: shell, mvvm, screen, caliburn.micro

It is possible have more active screen / view in one shell if I am using caliburn micro ?

Something like this, code for shell view - wpf window:

```
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_1" Grid.Row=1/>

        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_2" Grid.Row=2/>


        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_9" Grid.Row=9/>
```

Thank you for advice, or in which MVVM this possible?

Answer (score 3):

In case of AllActive conductor you will have inherited `Items` collection in your ShellViewModel. When calling `ActivateItem(vm)` View Model will be added into `Items` collection and when calling `DeactivateItem(vm, close: true)` - removed. Then in ShellView.xaml you can bind `Items` (collection of View Models) to `ItemsControl`.

**MyView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="AllActive_Test.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
class MyViewModel : Screen
{
    private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myVar;
        }
        set
        {
            myVar = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

**ShellView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="AllActive_Test.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        Width="300" Height="300">

    <Grid Background="White">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.AllActive, IShell
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
            vm.MyProperty = i;
            ActivateItem(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ShellView containing 3 active Screens]

Comment: Here are also interesting examples of composition: http://cocktail.ideablade.com/composing-view-models/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is possible with...

```
Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive
```

See [Screens, Conductors and Composition](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition) doc page.

1. Inherit the class above in your ShellViewModel.
2. Populate the ShellViewModel's Items property with the ViewModels for the views that you want to display within the ShellView.
3. Bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl (you should not need an ItemTemplate) in the ShellView to the Items property on the ShellViewModel.

I am fairly sure that Caliburn.Micro will look after the rest but I am unable to test at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, can you provide for me some simple example ho to use it Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive ? Some code for shell, view models, and view - XAML. Thank you

Comment: Check out the HelloScreens sample that comes with the CM download.

Comment: There is no sample with AllActive in HelloScreens sample.

Comment: Could someone guide me to an example that is working with Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive and includes the different screens like <ContentControl x:Name="ViewModelName" />